# One data from two get method

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, get, axios

I have two separate axios get method which map response data to separate data object. Then I map the data in render. I want to put data from both axios in to one object to map only one object in render. How could i do that?

One of two get function

```
getData() {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost/GetAll?", {
      params: { rok: this.state.rok, idUchwaly: "1" },
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + this.state.token }
    })
    .then(response =>
      response.data.map(data2 => ({
        IDA: `${data2.idZadania}`,
        idWersji: `${data2.idWersji}`,
        Dzial: `${data2.dzial}`
      }))
    )
    .then(data2 => {
      if (data2 == "") {
      } else {
        this.setState({ data2, isLoadingdane: true });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error }));
}
```

Then I map data into a table

```
{this.state.isLoadingdane ? (
  data2.map(user2 => {
    const { IDA, idWersji, Dział } = user2;
    return (
      <tr id={IDA}>
        <td>
          <p>{idWersji}</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>{Dzial}</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  })
) : (
  <tr>
    <td colSpan="3">
      <center>
        <p>Brak</p>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
)}
```

I want one table in which i could put values from both get function

something like this: {value from getData}{value from getData2}

Comment: ``[...data1, ...data2].map( /*...*/``?

Comment: it didn't work. it just maping first data and then the second below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the response to the axios request in state directly, you could return the promise and wait for both of the requests to finish with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and then merge the objects in both arrays into one array.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([this.getData(), this.getData2]).then(([data1, data2]) => {
      this.setState({
        data2: data1.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, ...data2[index] })),
        isLoadingdane: true
      });
    });
  }

  getData = () => {
    return axios
      .get("http://localhost/GetAll?", {
        params: { rok: this.state.rok, idUchwaly: "1" },
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + this.state.token }
      })
      .then(response =>
        response.data.map(data2 => ({
          IDA: `${data2.idZadania}`,
          idWersji: `${data2.idWersji}`,
          Dzial: `${data2.dzial}`
        }))
      );
  };

  getData2 = () => {
    return axios.get(/* ... */);
    // ...
  };

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: now i see small problem. when for example one json has 10 records and the second one has 6 records, the records doesn't fit. how can i add a comparison of idZadania to put a value in table in right place

Comment: @BartekMichułka That changes the question quite drastically, and it's not good practice to change the question after it has been answered. If you can't figure it out, consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question and someone will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Bartek, you need to map results like that:

```js
const first = [{
  x: 'x',
  y: 'y',
}];

const second = [{
  x: 'x',
  z: 'z',
}];

const all = first.map(o => ({ ...o, ...second.find(f => f.x === o.x)}));

console.log(all);
```